# Generate login cookie in shell (using curl?)

Tags: bash, authentication, curl, cookies, browser

I would like to generate a login cookie in the shell, before launching my browser, such that I am already logged into certain websites. Currently I am trying this with my own nextcloud server using the following command

```
curl --cookie test.txt --cookie-jar test.txt \
-d "user=***name***" \
-d "password=***password***" \
<my nextcloud server>/index.php/login
```

getting a cookie that looks like the following. However, placing this among my other cookies does not allow me to login.

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_<my nextcloud server>  FALSE   /nextcloud      TRUE       nc_sameSiteCookiestrict        true
#HttpOnly_<my nextcloud server>  FALSE   /nextcloud      TRUE          nc_sameSiteCookielax   true
#HttpOnly_<my nextcloud server>  FALSE   /nextcloud      TRUE          oc_sessionPassphrase  .....
#HttpOnly_<my nextcloud server> FALSE   /nextcloud      TRUE         ..... ...................
```

Recording with chromium the action of a normal login, a different cookie is generated out of the one below, is anyone familiar with this login method?
Thanks!

My goal would be an auto login script like [this one](https://surf.suckless.org/files/autologin/) for the surf browser

Answer (score 1):

If you try to connect to nextcloud with your browser while looking at the Network tab of your browser's development tool, you will see the exact request being made.

You need to do the exact same request again with Curl.

In your case you are missing the following settings:

`-X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-wwww-form-urlencoded"`

to make a request to send a form in POST.

But you are also missing the other hidden fields of the form including the requesttoken field.

This field is a token randomly generated when you arrive on the login page which is stored in a php session and is compared with the values of your form when you log in.
It is a security system to make bruteforce attacks more difficult.

To bypass this security system, you first need to make a request on the login page, extract the cookies generated and parse the content of the page to retrieve the requesttoken field.
Then you can made your second request to send the form with with your login and password and finaly get your authenticated cookies.

Good luck !